# How to create an array of property/value from an object using Ramda?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have an object like

```
const obj = {
   apple:'red',
   banana:'yellow'
}
```

I need to return an array with properties/values using ramda.

Example:

```
[
    {
        name: 'apple',
        value:'red'
    },
    {
        name: 'banana',
        value:'yellow'
    },
]
```

Answer (score 3):

A ramda solution:

```
R.pipe(
  R.toPairs,
  R.map(R.zipObj(['name', 'value']))
)(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that without any 3rd party lib, with [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), that returns an array with an array that contains key & value, map over it to convert it to an object.

```js
const obj = {
  apple: 'red',
  banana: 'yellow'
};

const result = Object.entries(obj)
  .map(([name, value]) => ({
    name,
    value
  }));

console.log(result);
```